# Today I try to viewBinding but end up with error

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-viewbinding

I try to viewbind from my xml file but end up with error. I copied exactly from youtube but still error. Both ActivityMainBinding is error.

Here my xml file code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here my kotlin code:

```
package com.haziqharis.myapplicationtest

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }
}
```

Here my gradle code

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.haziqharis.myapplicationtest"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

The error as photo below

[image: As you can see, both ActivityMainBinding is red color. I dont know why]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put below code to activity_main.xml file, outside of your ConstraintLayout.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

</layout>
```

Comment: @HaziqHaris If it helps you, you can use the check mark on top left of the question to accept it !

Comment: Here is a confusion between dataBinding and ViewBinding, for viewBinding you don't need this layout tag in your xml, you just need to enable viewBinding in build.gradle(app level) and then initialize the viewbinding in activity and pass its root in setContentView https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

Answer (score 0):

You should checkout [this article](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding) from Android Developers.

There some things that are clearly wrong in your implementation your view should have `<layout>` tag then in your `onCreate(`) methid you should use `ActivityMainBinding.setContentView()` no need to call regular `setContentView()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I made some change to my xml file. I specially make the `ConstraintLayout` element in a more global layout one.

This is my final code:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want are trying viewbinding, add this to your gradle (`build.gradle(:app)`)

```
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
```